# Preprocessor conditional distributed across `#include` files

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

Is this legal?

**`foo.h`**:

```
    #if 1
    #include "bar.h"
```

**`bar.h`**:

```
    #endif
```

**`foo.c`**

```
    #include "foo.h"
```

`clang-700.1.81` complains in a kind of a funny way:

```
    In file included from foo.c:1:
    In file included from ./foo.h:2:
    ./bar.h:1:2: error: #endif without #if
    #endif
```

(which means like it *did* `#include "bar.h"`)

```
    # 3 "./foo.h" 2
    In file included from foo.c:1:
    ./foo.h:1:2: error: unterminated conditional directive
    #ifndef FOO
```

(which means like it *didn't* `#include "bar.h"`).

I have an uneasy feeling that the preprocessor cares about more than a Standard mandates it to. Please correct me if I am wrong, or prove otherwise if I am right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not legal. All of the conditional directives which make up the conditional section must be in the same file, although the conditional groups may contain `#include` directives or nested conditional sections.

This constraint is made explicit by the grammar for preprocessing files (§ 6.10).

```
      preprocessing-file:
               group opt
      group:
               group-part
               group group-part
      group-part:
               if-section
               control-line
               text-line
               # non-directive
      if-section:
               if-group elif-groups opt else-group opt endif-line
```

The constraint is also implicit in §5.1.1.2 paragraph 4 which describes the functioning of the `#include` directive as a recursive execution of phases 1 through 4, rather than a simple textual inclusion:

> A #include preprocessing directive causes the named header or source file to be processed from phase 1 through phase 4, recursively.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. I think this is answered by the C11 standard in two places.

First we look at the grammar in §6.10, it's obvious that the `#if` and `#endif` must be in the same `preprocessing-file`. If the name itself of wasn't enough, we can look at §5.1.1.1 for the definition:

> 5.1.1.1 Program structure
>
> 1 A C program need not all be translated at the same time. The text of the program is kept
> in units called source files, (or preprocessing files) in this International Standard. A
> source file together with all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing
> directive #include is known as a preprocessing translation unit

Answer (score 1):

ISO/IEC 9899 has this sentence for translation phase 3:

> [cut] A source file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. [cut]

To me this means that a file containing a `#if` must have a matching `#endif`.

Comment: Close, but this is not what a preprocessing token is.